# R Regular expression to search citations of law using tidytext and tm

Tags: r, regex, tm, quanteda, tidytext

I use `tidytext`, `tm` and `quanteda`for text mining.

**I try to:**

1. filter a `tibble` with plain, processed text according to presence of a citation of law
2. count the number of the same citation per text document

Unfortunately, I am weak at using specific regex.

Here is a paragraph that shows typical legal citations:

> 4.1. Die selbstständige Tätigkeit als Arzt oder Ärztin bedarf einer Bewilligung des Kantons, auf dessen Gebiet sie ausgeübt wird (Art. 34
>   MedBG). Die Bewilligung wird erteilt, wenn die gesuchstellende Person
>   ein entsprechendes eidgenössisches Diplom besitzt (Art. 36 Abs. 1 lit.
>   a MedBG) und vertrauenswürdig ist sowie physisch und psychisch Gewähr
>   für eine einwandfreie Berufsausübung bietet (Art. 36 Abs. 1 lit. b
>   MedBG). Die Bewilligung wird entzogen, wenn ihre Voraussetzungen nicht
>   mehr erfüllt sind oder nachträglich Tatsachen festgestellt werden, auf
>   Grund derer sie hätte verweigert werden müssen (Art. 36 MedBG).

Swiss law is generally sturctured as follows (https://www.admin.ch/opc/de/classified-compilation/20040265/index.html):

1. **Article** (Art. x, while x is a number)
2. Paragraph (Abs. x, while x is a number)
3. Letter (lit. x, while x i a lowercase letter)
4. depending of the Code of Law even more subheader could present, such as "Satz 2",
5. **Code of Law** (mixed case letters)

Moreover, 2-4 are not mandatory or could be combinded e.g.:

> Art 34. MedBG
>
> Art. 42 Abs. 2 und 100 Abs. 1 MedBG

Even tough it would be very nice to have a regex that would specify every substructure of a given Article and Code of Law, (there are hundreds of them, many of them with tiny differences in 2. - 4)... if you have any idea how I could do that automatically, let me know ;D) I am only interessted in the Article and Code of Law (Article 1-67 and MedBG in this case)

**My approach**

I cleaned the text by removing tall letters and removed punctuation using `tolower` and `tm::removePunctuation` and got back to tidy data using `tidytext::tidy()`

```
> head(docs_tidy %>% select(id,text))
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  id                     text                                                                                                                
  <chr>                  <chr>                                                                                                               
1 31.12.2015_9C_911_2015 "\n      \n \nbundesgericht \ntribunal fédéral \ntribunale federale \ntribunal federal \n \n \n\n    \n  \n        ~
2 31.12.2015_9C_910_2015 "\n      \n \nbundesgericht \ntribunal fédéral \ntribunale federale \ntribunal federal \n \n \n\n    \n  \n        ~
3 31.12.2015_9C_934_2015 "\n      \n \nbundesgericht \ntribunal fédéral \ntribunale federale \ntribunal federal \n \n \n\n    \n  \n        ~
4 31.12.2014_9C_904_2014 "\n      \n \nbundesgericht \ntribunal fédéral \ntribunale federale \ntribunal federal \n \n \n\n    \n  \n        ~
5 31.12.2014_9C_907_2014 "\n      \n \nbundesgericht \ntribunal fédéral \ntribunale federale \ntribunal federal \n \n \n\n    \n  \n        ~
```

**What I miss:**
I thought about a regex that searches for 1 (Article) and skips the expressions from 2-4 until it reaches 5 (Code of Law).

> art 1.(code to identify unnecessary items from 2-4(e.g abs. 1
>   100){0,until medbg reached}medbg

If it is not possible to stop it at a specific point, it could be stopped after skipping about 8 items (that is the maximum I exspect between 1. and 5.)

```
lawCitation <- c("art. 1 medbg","art. 42 abs. 2 und 100 abs. 1 medbg","art. 1 abs. 1 lit a medbg","art. 36 abs. 1 lit. b medbg","art. 1 satz 2 bgg und abs. 1 lit a lit b","art. 22 totally random number 21 medbg")
```

`grepl("REGEX",lawCitation)` for `art. 1` and `medbg` should return `TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE`

**if I had a good regex, I would go on like this:**

```
# search docs for speficic Article from a specific Code of Law
dplyr::filter(docs_tidy, grepl("REGEX",text)) -> filtered
# count n of citations
filtered %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(citations=length(grep("REGEX",.)
```

Or I would try to write a function that searches my `tibble` for all Articles (art. 1-67) of medbg and counts them.

Comment: If you need a regex for something, you have to define exactly what you want and don't want. That's the _law_ of regular expressions.

Comment: Something like https://regex101.com/r/raQGwq/1 ?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. @sln I totally agree, however, I have a large dataset (100k docs) and the citation style differs with different Code of Law, it is not possible to be more specific than this: the item starts with "art. x" and stops with "y" whereas both x and y are known and its distance to each other is roughly not more than 20 digits , the space beween x/y consists out of a variable number of items such as abbrevations (e.g. abs. lit. i.v.m), single or combined numbers (e.g. 1, 3-5), single or combined characters (e.g. a, a-c). Is there mb. a better solution than regex for my case?

Comment: @ Jan, almost! I updated the test string. https://regex101.com/r/raQGwq/4. the problem is, that there is a variable amount of items between x and y and the citation does not always have brackets.

Comment: @captcoma: I am by no means an expert in Swiss law but it seems this heads in the right direction: https://regex101.com/r/raQGwq/5